# How does this Prolog code really work - Shuffle two Lists

Tags: list, recursion, prolog, shuffle, non-deterministic

I have the following code, **working**, that shuffles two lists:

```
shuffle([], [], []).
shuffle([X|Xs], Ys, [X|Zs]):-
          shuffle(Xs, Ys, Zs).
shuffle(Xs, [Y|Ys], [Y|Zs]):-
          shuffle(Xs, Ys, Zs).
```

I understand each part separately. The first clause receives two lists, one with `X` that is the *head*, `Xs` is the *tail*. In the result we "take" only the first list's *head*. The same with the second clause – we don't take `Xs` for the result, only the *head* of `Y`.

Prolog recursively separates the lists and then unifies them.

What I don't understand here is how it works? After it ended "taking out" all the `Xs`, it just "moves" to the second clause, to take the `Ys`? What triggers Prolog to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to prove a goal in Prolog for example: `shuffle([a],[c],L).` what Prolog does is to search in the database to find rules that much with the predicate shuffle.

In this case both second and third rule occur, so you have two options-choice points as called in Prolog:

***1st-choice point***: We examine second rule: `shuffle([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).` and applying that in our goal we get `[X|Xs] = [a]` (so `X = a, Xs = []`), `Ys = [c]`, and `L` is of the form `[a|Zs]`, and finally recursively `shuffle([],[c],Zs)` is called. This goal now only matches third rule and we get `Zs = [c|Zs']` and again recursively `shuffle([],[],Zs')` is called where now only first rule matches and we get `Zs' = []`. So from the first case examined we get `Zs = [a,c]`. Now we have left another case:

***2nd-choice point***: We examine third rule: `shuffle(Xs,[Y|Ys],[Y|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).` and applying that in our goal we get `Xs = [a], [Y|Ys] = [c]` (so `Y = c, Ys = []`), and `L` is of the form `[c|Zs]`, and finally recursively `shuffle([a],[],Zs)` is called. This goal now only matches second rule and we get `Zs = [a|Zs']` and again recursively `shuffle([],[],Zs')` is called where now only first rule matches and we get `Zs' = []`. So from the second case examined we get `Zs = [c,a]`.

So finally we get the two solutions. As you can see Prolog does a depth-first analysis on the choice points because it finds the first choice point and examines it and the goes on to the third and so on. The obvious problem here is that can you imagine the number of choice points for two-element lists e.g `shuffle([a,b],[c,d],L)` ?? It would be four choice points and for the general case of `Xs,Ys` the choice point are way too much.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. I do understand that the solution here goes for a lot of options (and that's what is asked from me). Just to make it clear to me - In any program, prolog first examines the first choice, FULLY, and then goes to the second choice?

Comment: Yes exactly, Prolog generates the choice points and does depth-first examination of each choice points. You may have seen that this process is generating the choice point tree and the path to find solutions is doing dfs traversal e.g here is an example that analyze that: https://www.cpp.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/3_1.html You can find plenty tutorial that all explain the same thing (as in the link) and show the tree that is generated.

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding all the X and Y and Z parts, what can we say about the **working** code:

1. You start with a query like `shuffle([1,2],[a,b],L).` and Prolog tries to solve it by solving the three `shuffle` rules.
2. One shuffle rule can be solved on its own, but only for empty lists, the other two rely on solving another case of the `shuffle` rule.
3. Whatever solution is found *must* go `shuffle -> shuffle -> [shuffle....] -> empty lists`. It must. If it could not match any shuffles at all, it would answer "false" and your code wouldn't work. If it bounced between shuffles forever it would infinite loop and give no answers and your code wouldn't work. It does work, so it must chain from the start, through a combination of shuffles, to the empty lists.

Prolog will try to solve from the top of the rules:

```
From the top:

A) shuffle([1,2],[a,b],L).  -no->  shuffle([],[],[]).
B) shuffle([1,2],[a,b],L).  -??->  shuffle([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).
B) shuffle([1,2],[a,b],L).  -??->  shuffle([X=1|Xs=[2]],Ys=[a,b],[X=1|Zs=??]) :- shuffle(Xs=[2],Ys=[a,b],Zs).

% A) fails as [1,2] does not match with []
% B) partially binds but is missing Zs. Solving to try and find the Zs is now:

shuffle(Xs=[2],Ys=[a,b],Zs).



From the top:

A) shuffle([2],[a,b],Zs).  -no->  shuffle([],[],[]).
B) shuffle([2],[a,b],Zs).  -??->  shuffle([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).
B) shuffle([2],[a,b],Zs).  -??->  shuffle([X=2|Xs=[]],Ys=[a,b],[X=2|Zs=??]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).

% A) fails as [2] does not match with []
% B) partially binds but is missing Zs. Solving to try and find the Zs is now:

shuffle(Xs=[],Ys=[a,b],Zs).



From the top:

A) shuffle([],[a,b],Zs).  -no->  shuffle([],[],[]).
B) shuffle([],[a,b],Zs).  -no->  shuffle([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).
C) shuffle([],[a,b],Zs).  -??->  shuffle(Xs,[Y|Ys],[Y|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).
C) shuffle([],[a,b],Zs).  -??->  shuffle(Xs=[],[Y=a|Ys=[b]],[Y=a|Zs=??]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).

% A) fails as [a,b] does not match with the second []
% B) fails as [] does not match with [X|Xs]
% C) partially binds but is missing Zs. Solving to try and find the Zs is now:

shuffle([],[b],Zs).



From the top:

A) shuffle([],[b],Zs).  -no->  shuffle([],[],[]).
B) shuffle([],[b],Zs).  -no->  shuffle([X|Xs],Ys,[X|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).
C) shuffle([],[b],Zs).  -??->  shuffle(Xs,[Y|Ys],[Y|Zs]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).
C) shuffle([],[b],Zs).  -??->  shuffle(Xs=[],[Y=b|Ys=[]],[Y=b|Zs=??]):- shuffle(Xs,Ys,Zs).

% A) fails as [b] does not match with the second []
% B) fails as [] does not match with [X|Xs]
% C) partially binds but is missing Zs. Solving to try and find the Zs is now:

shuffle([],[],Zs).



From the top:

A) shuffle([],[],Zs).  -no->  shuffle([],[],[]).

% A) succeeds. Zs can be []
```

This is a finished chain from the origin, through four shuffles, to the empty lists. During this chain, Zs has been constructed as `[1|?]` then `[1|[2|?]]` then `[1|[2|[a|?]]]` then `[1|[2|[a|[b|?]]]]` then `[1|[2|[a|[b|[]]]]]` which is complete, no missing anything. That binds to your `L` input for the first result.

It's gone through the shuffles `B B C C`.

---

But the search space is not exhausted, there might be more answers. If you ask for them it unwinds back up the chain to a place where it could have taken a different path. Instead of solving `shuffle([X|Xs]..` it can skip that one and dive down `shuffle(Xs` instead.

The two `shuffle` predicates with lots of values work together make a bounce pattern, which terminates with the three empty list cases:

```
[1,2],[a,b],Unknown
        \
         \
          \ ? shuffle shuffle shuffle
          /
         /
         \
      [],[],[]
```

One chain of logical connections is `B B C C A`. Another chain is `B C B C A` which results in the next answer `L=[1,a,2,b]`.

```
[1,2],[a,b],Unknown
       /   \       
      /     \
      \      \ B C B A
B B C C\     /
       |    /
       |    \
      [],[],[]
```

Once it's backtracked all the way back, at each choice swapped the shuffle for the other one and followed down the chain to the empty lists, it will have found 6 paths, 6 ways to bounce through the shuffles.

As you make the lists longer, the chains get longer. When it starts backtracking up the chain undoing its steps looking for other ways to go, there are more of them. More choice points, so it will find more solutions - proportional to the length of the inputs.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation! fantastic. Can you please, if you have time, look on my other question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52219327/cant-understand-why-is-prolog-looping-infinitly ?

Comment: I set out with "*I don't know how it works, but I'm hoping that by trying to explain it, I'll come to understand it*". A couple of hours and a couple of thousand words of writing and rewriting later, I think I do understand it. I suspected it always zig-zagged between the shuffles, it doesn't. I didn't know where the backtracking would kick in, now I do. I didn't know where the choicepoints came into it, now I do. Not sure my answer is any help to anyone else, but it helped me! :)