# Can't understand why is prolog looping infinitly

Tags: recursion, prolog, transitive-closure

From Bratko's book, [Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence (4th Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321417461) 
We have the following code which doesn't work -

```
anc4(X,Z):-
    anc4(X,Y),
    parent(Y,Z).
anc4(X,Z):-
    parent(X,Z).
```

In the book, on page 55, figure 2.15, is shown that `parent(Y,Z)` is kept calling until stack is out of memory.

What I don't understand is that prolog does a recursiv call to anc4(X,Y), and not to parent (Y,Z) first. Why doesn't prolog goes over and over to the **first line**, `anc4(X,Y)`, and rather goes to the second line?

Can you please elaborate why is the line `parent(Y,Z)` is kept being called?

Thank you.

Comment: `anc4(X, Z) :- anc4(X, Y), ...` right there. Prolog will keep selecting the first clause until it fails or succeeds. It does neither. It just keeps calling `anc4/2` again.

Comment: See [tag:failure-slice] on how to diagnose such problems.

Comment: And see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30328433/772868) for a general way to define this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The origin of your 'problem' (i.e. goals order) is deeply rooted in the basic of the language.

Prolog is based on the simple and efficient strategy of chronological backtracking, to implement [SLD resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution), and left recursive clauses, like `anc4/2`, cause an infinite recursion.
Indeed, the comma operator `(,)/2` stands for

> evaluate the right expression *only* if the left expression holds

So, order of goals in a clause is actually an essential part of the program.

For your concrete case,

```
... , parent(Y,Z).
```

cannot be called if

```
anc4(X,Y),
```

doesn't hold.

The counterpart to *goals order* is *clauses order*.

That is, the whole program has a different semantics after the clauses are exchanged:

```
anc4(X,Z):-
    parent(X,Z).
anc4(X,Z):-
    anc4(X,Y),
    parent(Y,Z).
```

To better understand the problem, I think it's worth to try this definition as well.

Answer (score 1):

Prolog cannot handle left recursion by default without a *tabling* mechanism. Only some Prolog systems support tabling and usually you need to explicitly declare which predicates are tabled.

If you're using e.g. XSB, YAP, or SWI-Prolog, try adding the following directive on top of your source file containing the definition for the `anc4/2` predicate:

```
:- table(anc4/2).
```

and retry your queries. The tabling mechanism detects when a query is calling a *variant* (*) of itself and suspends execution of that branch until a query answer is found and tries an alternative branch (provided in your case by the second clause). If that happens, execution is resumed with that answer.

(*) Variant here means that two terms are equal upon variable renaming.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, I'm not sure I understand what is a "tabling mechanism", I just don't understand why the second term of parent is calling.

Comment: Edited my answer with a brief/limited explanation of tabling. For a comprehensive description, see the manuals of a system supporting tabling.

Comment: @Alan, tabling is basically the implementation of memoization ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization ) in Prolog systems for efficiency.

Comment: @coder: actually, tabling isn't so easy as it sounds from your comment. While it has some convenience, implementing it required (I think) months to one of the top of the world SW engineer, with a deep understanding of what is going on. And using it requires a lot of experience, because - like constraints - it's basically a [leaky abstraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction)

Comment: @CapelliC, I totally agree I didn't referred to the complexity of achieving memoization in Prolog, the implementation is indeed a very complex think, I just explained the basic idea (e.g what is tabling) never said anything about the implementation...

Comment: @CapelliC: What is leaking in constraints?

Comment: @false: generally the control flow. Nothing warns a naive user about (mis)using standard Prolog constructs... Maybe it's such kind of lacking integration that led to development of Minizinc. A whole new language with limited scope on purpose of constraints modelling.